# Create a default Windows Authentication Domain and Username Prompt for a URL

Tags: ajax, windows, security, authentication, qlikview

I'm having a hard time researching my specific issue. Is there a way to tie a default Windows Authentication DOMAIN/Username to a specific URL?

I'm distributing a QlikView application in my IE Browser (AJAX) and it retains the last DOMAIN/Username used upon the next session. I would like to create a URL that generates a default Windows Authen. I didn't know if this could  be done through some URL parameter.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Channing

Comment: I don't think QlikView offers you this level of control. If the retention of the last user name bothers you, then you should change that in your browser's settings.

Comment: Thank you for your response!